# Can't increase my disk size

Tags: mac, hard-drive

[image]

I can't modify the "BOOTCAMP" disk to be larger or remove it completely, an error message will occur when attempting to do that. All I'm trying to do is install Xcode and since the size is too small I need to increase it.

Comment: Which partition is your bootcamp partition?

Comment: It looks like your bootcamp partition is only 28 GB. is this correct?

Comment: @jmh the bootcamp patrition is 40GB total and I used 28GB of it and I'm not sure which partition it's on.

Comment: Why do you want to change Boot Camp? Your main macOS partition looks like it has plenty of room left. Disk Utility will not let you change the size of Boot Camp anyway, Apple's only supported method is to remove it entirely & set back up as a fresh install, using Boot Camp Assistant. See wizdomonwheels' answer for a reliable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

When I've had to resize BootCamp volumes in the past I would use [CampTune](https://www.paragon-software.com/us/home/camptune/) from Paragon.

It looks like they added support for Catalina recently, so it should work well for you.

As for removing the BootCamp partition altogether, I've always used the Boot Camp Assistant to do that.

*Note: It's recommended that you make sure you've backed up your stuff before adjusting partition settings with either the CampTune, Disk Utility, or Boot Camp Assistant. I've had situations where things go south quickly when adjusting partitions.*